# How to test views that modify database data in Django?

Tags: django, unit-testing

I´m trying to test a view that changes the state of an object in my database and then saves it back. The problem is that I can´t get my unit Test to work with this view, even though if I try the view with my real database it works perfectly.

this is the view:

```
@login_required
def publicar_investigacion(request,id):
    context = RequestContext(request)

    try:
        inv = Investigacion.objects.get(pk=id)
        inv.estado = 1
        inv.save()
    except Investigacion.DoesNotExist:
        pass

    return HttpResponseRedirect('/admin/guatepediaapp/investigacion')
```

and this is my unit test:

```
   def test_ResultAprobarInvestigacion(self):
        inv = Investigacion.objects.create(pk=100,fecha=timezone.now())
        request = RequestFactory()

        user = User.objects.create_user(
            username='pablo', email='sib@ho.com', password='miSuperContraseniaa secreta')
        request.user = user

        response = v.publicar_investigacion(request,100)


        self.assertEqual(inv.estado, 1)
```

It´s worth mentioning that the defaul state of the variable estado when I create an Investigacion  is 2

This is what I get when running the tests:

```
   Failure
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\xampp\htdocs\guatepedia\guatepedia\Guatepedia\guatepediaapp\tests.py", line 34, in test_ResultAprobarInvestigacion
    self.assertEqual(inv.estado, 1)
AssertionError: 2 != 1
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `inv` variable in the test and the one in the view are not the same, even if they refer to the same database row: changes to one won't be shown in the other. You need to load the one in the test *after* calling the test: move the `inv = Investigacion...` line down to after the `response` line.

Comment: Hello. I don´t think I can do that since I won´t have any id to send to the view if I create the object after the view.But Maybe I did not understand your answer corectly. Thanks for the help

Comment: OK, good point. In that case you need to reload it after calling the view, by doing `inv = Investigacion.objects.get(pk=inv.pk)`.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that Investigacion.DoesNotExist exception is raised. Can you try this, instead of hardcoding the pk.

```
   def test_ResultAprobarInvestigacion(self):
        inv = Investigacion.objects.create(fecha=timezone.now())
        request = RequestFactory()

        user = User.objects.create_user(
            username='pablo', email='sib@ho.com', password='miSuperContraseniaa secreta')
        request.user = user

        response = v.publicar_investigacion(request,inv.id)


        self.assertEqual(inv.estado, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I´m still getting the same error.